# Automate the changing of code capitalization in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, code-formatting

There are a variety of good tools available to auto-correct and warn about coding violations, but all that I've seen have left out any standards as they relate to the capitalization of different aspect of the code. For instance, we want to enforce that all method calls in our code start with a lower case letter, and I have yet to find anything (outside of writing a regex) that can do this? Ideally, we would also want to enforce rules on method parameters and local variables if possible. Is there an easy method for doing this?

Comment: If you implement this yourself or use a third-party tool, make sure you read Apple's Coding Guidelines for Cocoa documentation thoroughly. For example, on method naming, the guidelines say: "You may begin a method name with a well-known acronym in uppercase (such as TIFF or PDF)." Automating validation could end up being trickier than it might at first seem.

Comment: @jlehr - This is true, but we have a large codebase where our coding standards changed (or were not followed) and it would be easier to do small corrections for mistakes then the whole thing by hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any code styling tool like checkstyle for Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385764/is-there-any-code-styling-tool-like-checkstyle-for-objective-c)

Comment: @jeffamaphone The items mentioned in your post do not handle capitalization

Comment: Be careful with stringent enforcement. For example, `+[NSURL URLWithString]` would fail "all method calls in our code start with a lower case letter".

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I was hoping there was a fairly intelligent code aware solution available.

Comment: You should make the coding guidelines clear to all developers in your team and just blame everyone who violates them every time they violate them. Trust in your developers, they know (probably) how to code ;)

Comment: @VWGolf2 - That is what we will do going forward. The problem is 5 years of legacy code prior to the rules going into effect. It would be nice to be consistent, but it would also be nice not to spend days changing the methods and variables.